# Ionic compound formation

Tags: ionic-compounds

Why do oxygen atoms differ in number in the compund Aluminate and Arsenate even they have the same suffixes ... Where Aluminate has 3 oxygen and Arsenate has 4 oxygen atoms.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix *-ate* depends on the relative number of Oxygen. It does not depend on the absolute number of O atoms. This was decided a lot time ago,  in the beginning of the 19th century :

An acid must contain at least one H atom, and its symbol $\ce{H}$ is written first. It reacts with any hydroxide giving a salt and water.

1. If the acid contains only one other element X, its name would be *hydro-X-ic acid*, and its salts are named *X-ide*. Example : 
   $\ce{HCl}$ is *hydrochloric acid*, and its sodium salt $\ce{NaCl}$ is named *sodium chloride.*
2. Acids containing $\ce{H}$, $\ce{1 X}$ and $\ce{O}$ atom have a name depending on the number of different acids known containing these elements.

2a. If only one acid formula is known with $\ce{H}$, $1$ $\ce{X}$ and $\ce{O}$, its name is *X-ic acid*, and its salts (or ions) are  *X-ate*. Today, the criteria of the "oxidation number" of $\ce{X}$ has replaced the "number of Oxygen atoms included in the formula".

Ex.: Only one acid formula is known containing $1$ $\ce{C}$ atom : $\ce{H_2CO_3}$. This is the *carbonic acid*, and its sodium salt $\ce{Na_2CO_3}$ is *sodium* *carbonate* : its name does not depend on the number of $\ce{O}$ atoms in the formula of the substance.

This also the case of "your" aluminate. As Aluminum has only one oxidation number, namely +3,  the ion $\ce{AlO_3^{3-}$ is called aluminate

2b. If two acids are known with H, $1$ $\ce{X}$ and $\ce{O}$, the acid with the highest number of $\ce{O}$ atoms (today : the highest oxidation number of X) is named after the rule $2$a. The acid with the least number of $\ce{O}$ atoms is named by changing *-ic* to *-ous*, and its salts by changing *-ate* by *-ite*. Today, the concept of "oxidation number" has replaced the number of Oxygen atoms.

Example. In the beginning of the 19th century, only two acids were known with Nitrogen or Phosphorus, namely $\ce{HNO_3}$ and $\ce{HNO_2}$, or $\ce{H_3PO_4}$ and $\ce{H_3PO_3}$. Well ! $\ce{HNO_3}$ was called *nitric* *acid*, and $\ce{HNO_2}$ was called *nitrous acid*. And of course $\ce{H_3PO_4}$ was called *phosphoric acid* and $\ce{H_3PO_3}$ was called *phosphorous acid*. Their salts are called *nitrate, nitrite, phosphate* and *phosphite*.

This is the case for "your" Arsenic, which may have oxidation number +3 or +5. With +5, it produces the ion arsenate $\ce{AsO_4^{3-}}$, where the number of Oxygen atoms is not directly related to its name.

2c. If there are more than $2$ different acids with $\ce{H}$, $1$ $\ce{X}$ and some $\ce{O}$ atoms, prefixes are used for the extremes. The acid with the biggest number of $\ce{O}$ gets prefix *hypo-* for the smallest and *per-* for the highest.

Example. Four acids are known if $\ce{X}$ is Chlorine : $\ce{HClO, HClO_2, HClO_3, HClO_4}$. Their names are respectively : *hypochlorous, chlorous, chloric* and *perchloric acid* Their sodium salts are called *hypochlorite, chlorite, chlorate and perchlorate.*

There exists other prefixes for the cases where the acid contains more than 1 $\ce{X}$ atom, and for the case where $\ce{2}$ acids have the same $\ce{X}$ atom with the same oxidation number, but a different number of $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms.